# File uploading in django

Tags: django, file

This is my code :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

<input type="file" name="myfile">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

{% if uploaded_file_url %}
<p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

How do I add a file and save it in media directory of application in Django project?

Comment: are  u planning to save this file into model?

Comment: i am trying to save a file in media directory of application in django

Comment: ok. but in your scenario do you push the file to database along with uploading it to `media/` folder ? or you just need to save it to `media/` folder without pushing to database  ?

Comment: i just want to upload a text file in the server from a local machine using django framework..I have written a template which has the file upload option on the userinterface..but i am not able to upload a file

Comment: pushing file in database along wiht media/folder or just saving in mdeia/.both are fine..i just need to be able to upload a file..i have read the documetn but not of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view.py` from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html should work for you !

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile) # saves the file to `media` folder
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename) # gets the url
        return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html')
```

Comment: i have used the view and simple_upload.html from the link..but not working

Comment: Did you add these in settings `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Comment: getting multivlaue error in request.files['myfile']

Answer (score 2):

[File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/) are covered in the Django Documentation.

There are slight differences depending on if you're trying to upload a file to a `Model` that got a `FileField` or `ImageField`, or if you just simply want to upload a file to your server that does not belong to any model using the `Form` class.

Please notice, Django have a `Form` class ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/)) that help you generate forms and handle the `POST` request with validation and so on. Use this class instead of writing your own HTML code.

### Upload File Without Model ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads))

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()

# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

### Upload File With Model ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model))

```
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ModelFormWithFileField

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelFormWithFileField(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = ModelFormWithFileField()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```